# Login Failing with no route matches error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I'm trying to learn how to write a login system using Rails, but I feel like I'm hacking away at this right now, I followed this guide:

http://rubysource.com/rails-userpassword-authentication-from-scratch-part-ii/

But I'm not sure if it was developed for Rails 4 and Ruby 2.

I keep getting this error:

[image: Rails Framework Error]

I have a feeling it's to do with the controller for the sessions, but I'm not entirely sure so I'll include all my files.

User.rb

```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
    EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+\z/
    validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
    validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :format => EMAIL_REGEX
    validates :password, :confirmation => true #password_confirmation attr
    validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create

    before_save :encrypt_password
    after_save :clear_password

    def encrypt_password
        if password.present?
            self.salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
            self.encrypted_password= BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, salt)
        end
    end

    def clear_password
        self.password = nil
    end
    def self.authenticate(username_or_email="", login_password="")
        if EMAIL_REGEX.match(username_or_email)
            user = User.find_by_email(username_or_email)
        else
            user = User.find_by_username(username_or_email)
        end

        if user && user.match_password(login_password)
            return user
        else
            return false
        end
    end

    def match_password(login_password="")
        encrypted_password == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(login_password, salt)
    end
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :save_login_state, :only => [:new, :create]
    def new
        @user = User.new
    end
    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        if @user.save
            flash[:notice] = "You Signed up successfully"
            flash[:color]= "valid"
        else
            flash[:notice] = "Form is invalid"
            flash[:color]= "invalid"
        end
        render "new"
    end
    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

    before_filter :authenticate_user, :only => [:home, :profile, :setting]
    before_filter :save_login_state, :only => [:login, :login_attempt]

    def login

    end

    def login_attempt
        authorized_user = User.authenticate(params[:username_or_email],params[:login_password])
        if authorized_user
            session[:user_id] = authorized_user.id
            flash[:notice] = "Wow Welcome again, you logged in as #{authorized_user.username}"
            redirect_to(:action => 'home')
        else
            flash[:notice] = "Invalid Username or Password"
            flash[:color]= "invalid"
            render "login"  
        end
    end
    def logout
        session[:user_id] = nil
        redirect_to :action => 'login'
    end
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  protected
    def authenticate_user
        unless session[:user_id]
            redirect_to(:controller => 'sessions', :action => 'login')
            return false
        else
            # set current user object to @current_user object variable
            @current_user = User.find session[:user_id]
            return true
        end
    end

    def save_login_state
        if session[:user_id]
            redirect_to(:controller => 'sessions', :action => 'home')
            return false
        else
            return true
        end
    end
end
```

login.html.erb

```
<% @page_title = "UserAuth | Login" -%>
<div class= "Sign_Form">
    <h1>Log in</h1>
    <%= form_tag :sessions => :login_attempt do %>
        <p>Username or Email:</br> <%= text_field_tag(:username_or_email) %></p>
        <p>Password:</br> <%= password_field_tag :login_password %></p>
        <%= submit_tag("Log In") %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
BillingSystem::Application.routes.draw do
    root :to => "sessions#login"
    match "signup", :to => "users#new", via: [:get, :post]
    match "login", :to => "sessions#login", via: [:get, :post]
    match "logout", :to => "sessions#logout", via: [:get, :post]
    match "home", :to => "sessions#home", via: [:get, :post]
    match "profile", :to => "sessions#profile", via: [:get, :post]
    match "setting", :to => "sessions#setting", via: [:get, :post]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using rails 4 and Ruby 2, right?

1. `match` is no longer catches all routes, try `get`
2. Look at Devise gem

Comment: I'm trying to learn how to do a login from scratch, as I think it would be worthwhile as it's a fundamental element of your system, so it's worthwhile knowing the inner workings of it, rather than using something everyone uses and knows, just because it's easier.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your the url that you are posting your form to (root_url or /) does not handle a post request (and it usually should not). The form is posting to root because you are not specifying a url so it defaults to the current one (root) to post your form to. From you routes it should be something similar to this:

```
<% @page_title = "UserAuth | Login" -%>
<div class= "Sign_Form">
    <h1>Log in</h1>
    <%= form_tag "/login", :sessions => :login_attempt do %>
        <p>Username or Email:</br> <%= text_field_tag(:username_or_email) %></p>
        <p>Password:</br> <%= password_field_tag :login_password %></p>
        <%= submit_tag("Log In") %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

please see the api doc for more related to this: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag

Another note, I would not recommend looking into Devise until you are a bit more familiar with rails, they actually advise against it themselves. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#starting-with-rails

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me I tried the same tutorial.
root :to => "sessions#login"
get "signup", :to => "users#new"
get "login", :to => "sessions#login"
post "login_attempt", :to => "sessions#login_attempt"
get "logout", :to => "sessions#logout"
get "home", :to => "sessions#home"
get "profile", :to => "sessions#profile"
get "setting", :to => "sessions#setting"
resources :users